# Calculated columns should be where in MVVM model?

Tags: mvvm

I have a WPF DataGrid displaying Products. I have two fields price and mass in that which are actually the properties of Product class. I need to show a seperate column in grid name MultipliedValue = price * mass. As per MVVM model where should i do it ?

1) In model by making a readonly property.

2) In converter so that only my UI will be aware of that?

3) or in View model?

Please suggest which option i should choose and why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would disregard option #2 from the beginning -- converters should be used only to account for implementation details of the UI, and specifically in MVVM perhaps not even then (as you can do the conversion inside the ViewModel, which is option #3 and more convenient).

Between #1 and #3, in this case IMHO it's best to go with #1 -- price is not something that's only relevant for your UI and of course the concept of price (and how it is derived) is going to stay fixed throughout your application. Both the UI and your backend may choose to use this property or not.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue differently (than @jon). I put in the model only properties that I would like to serialize (say, from the server). Computed properties don't serialize, and hence they aren't in the model.

Recently, my favorite Model/View Model paradigm as as follow: Product is a class in the Model, that has nothing but the simplest getters and setters. ProductVm is a class in the VM, which contains Product, and has the additional VM logic. Most importantly, the property changed notification - which in my opinion is also part of the VM and not the model.

```
// Model:
class Product {
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Mass { get; set; }
}

// View Model:
class ProductVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Product _product;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public double Price {
        get { return _product.Price; }
        set { _product.Price = value; raise("Price"); raise("Total"); }
    }

    public double Mass {
        get { return _product.Mass; }
        set { _product.Mass = value; raise("Mass"); raise("Total"); }
    }

    public double total {
        get { return Price * Mass; }
    }

    private void raise(string name) {
        if( PropertyChanged ) {
            PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name) );
        }
    }

    public ProductVm( Product p ) {
        _product = p;
    }

    public ProductVm() {
        // in case you need this
        _product = new Product();
    }
}
```

Yes, there is a lot of boilerplate here, but once you do all the typing, you'll find this separation between Model and ViewModel very helpful. My 2 cents.

Note: I think @Jon approach is also correct, and is reasons are valid. I don't think there is one answer.

Comment: By using your design, properties defined in Model will re-defined in ViewModel mostly.  Also, you defined the business rules in ViewModel but not Model.  This seems contradict to the MVVM patterns.  However, your design seems interest too.

Comment: I disagree with this design. You have put the business logic (Total field) in the view model which is part of the application layer. Plus I don't understand why you are not implementing **INotifyPropertyChanged** on the Model since it makes everything a lot easier.

Comment: Thank you @HosseinShahdoost. I'll explain: about INotifyPropertyChanged not being in the mode: this is easy. We want to keep the model as clean and as independent as possible. For example - the model is what we serialize to send over the wire. It should always contain nothing but data, and maybe (there are great arguments each way) verification logic for the data. As for the Total field, I'll ask you: What is the application layer in MVVM appliation? Is that the view? is that the model (then again, would you serialize the Total)?

Comment: I disagree with big models as well, but An only data model (more like an old structure) is also a bad practice. There is nothing wrong with serializing a model which implements INotifyPropertyChanged and the Total field can be omitted on the serialization process too, so it wouldn't be a problem. 
But what if you want to show the Model (and specifically the Total field) on a grid? Since the Total is not available there.

Comment: And about the application layer. I recommend you take a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=PandP.40).aspx  , Business logic is best to be taken care of out side the ViewModel. ViewModel must only do the PresentationLogic such as Localizations, ... and not the Business and Data Logic